# CKEDITOR en django, problemas con las etiquetas

Tags: javascript, html5, django, css3

- Hola, tengo el siguiente problema, instale CKEDITOR en una web con django que estoy haciendo, y al publicar un post, el post aparece en la web pero con las etiquetas

  visibles, de esta forma (dejo imagen)
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Como puedo hacer que desaparezcan esas etiquetas de html ?, en inspeccionar el codigo fuente desde el navegador se ve esto (dejo imagen)
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que al visualizar desde la web no se vean esas etiquetas.

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo resolvi, solo habia que ponerle safe al momento de llamar la variable
por ejemplo yo lo tenia asi {{project.description}} pero habia que ponerlo asi {{project.description|safe}}